# Installing Java 8 on a Mac: Why can't I download the file? It re-directs to a log-in

Tags: java, macos

I've installed Java 8 on Linux machines before, but I just tried installing it on a friend's Mac and couldn't get it to work.  I went to the Oracle page, down to Java JDK 8, accepted the license agreement, and clicked the download link for Java 8.  For whatever reason, it then directs me to log in to an Oracle account.

I re-tried the procedure for Java 12, and it worked.  I could download the `.pkg` file just fine.

I can't begin to guess what's going on here.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Unfortunately such questions are off topic here, but I faced a similar issue last week and gave up in the end...

Comment: Create oracle account and download by login into that username and password.

Comment: I do believe this is off topic as well, going to see if the moderators flag it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End of life versions require login for years, according to [/u/beltedgalaxy/](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/6ag6qk/oracle_not_allowing_jdk_downloads_without_an/)
Try [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot), the community driven implemintation of JDK.